# How to avoid key collision while using Play! Cache object?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, ehcache

In Play!, `play.api.Cache` is a singleton object, thus globally accessible from all other objects. And, by its nature, a cache is a mutable object. Global mutable state like this is generally very problematic.

In particular, there's the potential problem of key collision. Two different classes (which are otherwise loosely coupled from each other) can, by accident, use the same key to store some value. Then, one of the updates would be overridden by the other.

One possible solution to this problem would be creating a new class, which could even delegate to the global `Cache`, but adding some kind of "namespace" to the key. Even though this wouldn't be hard to implement, it would be better if there was already some standard solution to this problem (preferably implemented on Play! itself). Is there any?

Comment: +1 but are you not already namespacing your keys? I generally name the cache key after the domain in question + some other unique identifier, like a user id, timestamp, etc. Clearing the cache is a bigger concern for me, how to clear cache by key prefix? That would be highly useful.

Comment: Just suggestion: I'm always trying to keep convention for cache keys: `classname.methodname.additionalparams.moreadds` it isn't brilliant solution, however helps a little. BTW still have no time to look closer into the Ehcache `indexes`/`search API` maybe using them would allow to avoid clashes.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to put an identifier to your key. For example, given a `User` class, you use `"user"+user.id` as key when saving it to the cache. That way you don't have to worry about clashes.

Be aware that I'm considering the cache used by a single Play application. By default EhCache uses the same JVM space Play is using, so there can't be 2 different `User` classes in there. If you are using an external cache in which several apps are sharing the cache, then you should add some namespace to they key (`appName.class.classId` or similar). But that should not be an issue in standalone Play applications.

About the comment that talks on how to empty the cache, usually you shouldn't need to worry about it. In theory, long term, stale keys will be dropped from the cache as they are not used. Details on how/when may change based on cache implementation (LRU, etc) but unless you have a very specific constraint, should not be a problem.